# Logging in using custom window in Kodi addon gives segmentation fault

Tags: 14.04, xbmc, kodi, add-on

I have developed a Kodi 14 addon to show list of books for which I require user to log in first I did it using simple Dailogwindow on kodi which worked well but when i did the same thing using custom window. When I input userid and password and click on log in button it shuts down kodi and shows this on terminal.

> Segmentation fault (core dumped) Crash report available at
>   /home/jaysheel/kodi_crashlog-20150722_100335.log

And here's the crash report.

> ######## Kodi CRASH LOG
>   
>   ########## SYSTEM INFO ################  Date: Wed Jul 22 10:03:35 IST 2015  Kodi Options:   Arch: x86_64  Kernel: Linux
>
> 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015  Release: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr
>
> ######## END SYSTEM INFO
>   
>   ######### STACK TRACE
>   
>   ####### END STACK TRACE
>   
>   ########### LOG FILE
>
> ﻿10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to:
>   special://masterprofile/ 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Starting Kodi (14.2 Git:7cc53a9).
>   Platform: Linux x86 64-bit 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Using
>   Release Kodi x64 build 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Kodi
>   compiled Mar 27 2015 by GCC 4.8.2 for Linux x86 64-bit version 3.13.11
>   (199947) 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Running on Ubuntu 14.04.2
>   LTS, kernel: Linux x86 64-bit version 3.13.0-57-generic 10:02:44
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: FFmpeg statically linked, version:
>   2.4.6-xbmc-2.4.6-Helix 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Host CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz, 4 cores available 10:02:44
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to:
>   /usr/share/kodi 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/
>   is mapped to: /usr/lib/kodi 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/jaysheel/.kodi/userdata
>   10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to:
>   /home/jaysheel/.kodi 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/jaysheel/.kodi/temp 10:02:44
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: The executable running is:
>   /usr/lib/kodi/kodi.bin 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Local
>   hostname: orion 10:02:44 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Log File is
>   located: /home/jaysheel/.kodi/temp/kodi.log 10:02:44 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE:
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: load settings... 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Enumerated PULSE devices: 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE:     Device 1 10:02:45 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : Default 10:02:45 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default 10:02:45 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Default Output Device (PULSEAUDIO)
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      :
>   AE_DEVTYPE_PCM 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_channels 
>   : FL,FR 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates
>   :
>   5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     :
>   AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:     Device 2 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      :
>   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 10:02:45 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra:
>   Speakers (PULSEAUDIO) 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   m_channels        : FL,FR 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   m_sampleRates     :
>   5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     :
>   AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: No settings file to load
>   (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml) 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: No settings file to load
>   (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml) 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Default DVD Player: dvdplayer 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Default Video Player: dvdplayer 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting.
>   Level 0. 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Log level changed to
>   "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL" 10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Loading player
>   core factory settings from
>   special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml. 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Loading player core factory
>   settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml. 10:02:45
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist.
>   Skipping. 10:02:45 T:140130884937472  NOTICE: Thread ActiveAE start,
>   auto delete: false 10:02:45 T:140130944833280  NOTICE: Thread AESink
>   start, auto delete: false 10:02:45 T:140130944833280  NOTICE:
>   PulseAudio: Opened device Default in pcm mode with Buffersize 150 ms
>   10:02:45 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Running database version Addons16
>   10:02:46 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: ADDONS: Using repository
>   repository.xbmc.org 10:02:46 T:140130918831872  NOTICE: Thread
>   PeripBusCEC start, auto delete: false 10:02:46 T:140130910439168 
>   NOTICE: Thread PeripBusUSBUdev start, auto delete: false 10:02:46
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Setup SDL 10:02:46 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: Checking resolution 15 10:02:46 T:140131360040896  NOTICE:
>   Using visual 0x20 10:02:46 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: GL_VENDOR =
>   Intel Open Source Technology Center 10:02:46 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: GL_RENDERER = Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 10:02:46
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: GL_VERSION = 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3 10:02:46
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION = 1.20 10:02:46
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: GL_EXTENSIONS = GL_ARB_multisample
>   GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax
>   GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset
>   GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array
>   GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D
>   GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters
>   GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels
>   GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal
>   GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
>   GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp
>   GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
>   GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
>   GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
>   GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
>   GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
>   GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
>   GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add
>   GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
>   GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square
>   GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection
>   GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
>   GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression
>   GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
>   GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos
>   GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle
>   GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow
>   GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
>   GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
>   GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap GL_EXT_stencil_two_side
>   GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels
>   GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers
>   GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects
>   GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers
>   GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
>   GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart
>   GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
>   GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite
>   GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync
>   GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
>   GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
>   GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
>   GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
>   GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float
>   GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
>   GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle
>   GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
>   GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
>   GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable
>   GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil
>   GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced
>   GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array
>   GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query
>   GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_ARB_copy_buffer
>   GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced
>   GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
>   GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
>   GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
>   GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
>   GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
>   GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_debug_output
>   GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
>   GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
>   GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
>   GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
>   GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
>   GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm
>   GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_ARB_get_program_binary
>   GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
>   GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5
>   GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment
>   GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax
>   GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
>   GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug
>   GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge 10:02:47 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: Running database version Addons16 10:02:47 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: Running database version ViewModes6 10:02:47 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE: Running database version Textures13 10:02:47 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE: Running database version MyMusic48 10:02:47 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: Running database version MyVideos90 10:02:47 T:140131360040896
>   NOTICE: Running database version TV26 10:02:47 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: Running database version Epg8 10:02:47 T:140131360040896 
>   NOTICE: start dvd mediatype detection 10:02:47 T:140131359577856 
>   NOTICE: Thread DetectDVDMedia start, auto delete: false 10:02:48
>   T:140131360040896 WARNING: JSONRPC: Could not parse type
>   "PVR.Details.Channel" 10:02:48 T:140131360040896 WARNING: JSONRPC:
>   Could not parse type "PVR.Details.ChannelGroup.Extended" 10:02:48
>   T:140131360040896 WARNING: JSONRPC: Could not parse type
>   "GUI.Property.Value" 10:02:48 T:140131360040896 WARNING: JSONRPC:
>   Could not parse type "Setting.Details.SettingList" 10:02:48
>   T:140130553673472  NOTICE: Thread LanguageInvoker start, auto delete:
>   false 10:02:48 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: initialize done 10:02:48
>   T:140130545280768  NOTICE: Thread LanguageInvoker start, auto delete:
>   false 10:02:48 T:140131360040896  NOTICE: Running the application...
>   10:02:49 T:140130553673472  NOTICE: -->Python Interpreter
>   Initialized<-- 10:02:50 T:140130545280768  NOTICE: Previous line
>   repeats 1 times. 10:02:50 T:140130545280768  NOTICE:  StorageServer
>   Module loaded RUN 10:02:50 T:140130545280768  NOTICE:
>   StorageClient-2.5.4 Starting server 10:02:51 T:140130515814144 
>   NOTICE: Thread JobWorker start, auto delete: true 10:02:51
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: starting zeroconf publishing 10:02:51
>   T:140131360040896  NOTICE: ES: Starting event server 10:02:51
>   T:140130499028736  NOTICE: Thread JobWorker start, auto delete: true
>   10:02:51 T:140130010523392  NOTICE: Thread TCPServer start, auto
>   delete: false 10:02:51 T:140130002130688  NOTICE: Thread JobWorker
>   start, auto delete: true 10:02:51 T:140130018916096  NOTICE: Thread
>   EventServer start, auto delete: false 10:02:51 T:140130018916096 
>   NOTICE: ES: Starting UDP Event server on 0.0.0.0:9777 10:02:51
>   T:140130018916096  NOTICE: UDP: Listening on port 9777 10:02:51
>   T:140131358549760  NOTICE: Thread RSSReader start, auto delete: false
>   10:02:51 T:140129967519488  NOTICE: Thread FileCache start, auto
>   delete: false 10:02:55 T:140129993737984  NOTICE: Previous line
>   repeats 2 times. 10:02:55 T:140129993737984  NOTICE: Thread
>   BackgroundLoader start, auto delete: false 10:02:57 T:140130553673472 
>   NOTICE: Thread LanguageInvoker start, auto delete: false 10:02:57
>   T:140130553673472  NOTICE: -->Python Interpreter Initialized<--
>   10:03:01 T:140130553673472  NOTICE: sys.argv 10:03:01
>   T:140130553673472  NOTICE: params: 10:03:01 T:140130553673472  NOTICE:
>   [] 10:03:02 T:140129967519488  NOTICE: Thread FileCache start, auto
>   delete: false 10:03:09 T:140130553673472  NOTICE: 1 10:03:09
>   T:140130553673472  NOTICE: -------------------------- Not logged in
>   10:03:14 T:140129967519488  NOTICE: Thread BackgroundLoader start,
>   auto delete: false
>
> ######### END LOG FILE
>   
>   ###### END Kodi CRASH LOG

Any help or suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is solved in new version of kodi